# how to get the element that triggers an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, position

I would like to show loading image near the element that start the request.
Example:

```
 $('#loading').hide()
 .ajaxStart(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
    $(this).show().position({my: "top center", at: "top center", of: event.target});
 })
 .ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
 });
```

event.target.id returns the `#loading` element. How can i get the id of the element that triggered the event?

Comment: sorry. returns #loading

Comment: ok got it .ajaxStart(function(elem) {
                                                                    
                                                                    alert(event.target);

Comment: `alert(this);` should work too, then.

Comment: I guess This way you are getting the id of the loader only